# Cambiar valores de elementos radioButton a ComboBox!

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola Buenos dias a todos, lo que pasa es que estoy desarrollando como una migración de un simulador, y el problema es: que unos radiobuttons, se cargan ciertos parametros al momento de pincharlo y esos valores se llenan en un input dependiendo cual sea, y lo que quiero es que que esa misma funcionalidad se haga con un comboBox, que al momento de seleccionar cierta opcion se se cargue el input con normalidad, este es mi codigo js y html dentro de un jsp:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simulador Pensión</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
        <script src="../js/jquery_v1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../comun/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../comun/js/EnmascaraV2-AEM.js"></script>

            <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/aplicativos/simulador-pensiones/globos/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/aplicativos/simulador-pensiones/seleccion.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/seleccion.js"></script>

       <!--Para QA-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_MD_cta.css">
        <!--fin-->
        <!--Ruta Mi local-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style_MD_cta.css">

        <script type="text/javascript">

            <%
            /**
             * ***********************************
             * Migracion everis 03/Octubre/2013 autor: Victor Lujan
        ************************************
             */
            %>
            //Declaración de Variables Globales
            //******************************************************
            //CAMBIAR ESTAS CANTIDADES ANUALMENTE  //se cambió 25-Marzo-14
            var FIJO1 = 2046.73;//Salario Actual
            var FIJO2 = 2343.38;//PMG Actual
            var FIJO3 = 2253.85;//PMG Anterior
            var a = 0, b = 0, r = 0, c = 0;
            //******************************************************


            var pension = '<%=Integer.parseInt((request.getParameter("pension") == null) ? "0" : request.getParameter("pension"))%>';
            var string_pension;
            var string_seguro = "";
            if (pension == "1") {
                string_pension = "Invalidez";
            } else if (pension == "2") {
                string_pension = "Incapacidad";
            } else if (pension == "3") {
                string_pension = "Viudez y Orfandad";
            } else if (pension == "4") {
                string_pension = "Viudez";
            } else if (pension == "5") {
                string_pension = "Orfandad";
            } else if (pension == "6") {
                string_pension = "Ascendencia";
            } else {
                string_pension = "";
            }

            var seg = '<%=(request.getParameter("seguro") == null) ? "0" : request.getParameter("seguro")%>';
            if (seg = "1") {
                string_seguro = "invalidez";
            } else if (seg = "2") {
                string_seguro = "riesgos de trabajo";
            } else if (seg = "3") {
                string_pseguro = "Viudez y Orfandad";
            }


            $(function () {


                $('input[name=valorpension]').click(function () {
                    if ($('select:option[name=valorpension]:checked').val() == 1) {
                        $('#PMG').val(FIJO2);
                    } else if ($('select:option[name=valorpension]:checked').val() == 2)
                        $('#PMG').val(FIJO3);
                });


                /////***** Datos  paso 2 ******
                var HON = '<%=request.getParameter("HON")%>';
                document.getElementById("HON").value = HON;
                var HOS = '<%=request.getParameter("HOS")%>';
                document.getElementById("HOS").value = HOS;
                var HOD = '<%=request.getParameter("HOD")%>';
                document.getElementById("HOD").value = HOD;
                var ASC = '<%=request.getParameter("ASC")%>';
                document.getElementById("ASC").value = ASC;
                var esposa = '<%=(request.getParameter("esposa") == null) ? "false" : request.getParameter("esposa")%>';
                document.getElementById("esposa").value = esposa;
                //  /****** Datos del index ******/
                var seguro = '<%=Integer.parseInt((request.getParameter("seguro") == null) ? "0" : request.getParameter("seguro"))%>';
                document.getElementById("seguro").value = seguro;
                var pension = '<%=Integer.parseInt((request.getParameter("pension") == null) ? "0" : request.getParameter("pension"))%>';
                document.getElementById("pension").value = pension;
                //***** Datos paso3
                var SP = '<%=Double.parseDouble((request.getParameter("SP") == null) ? "0" : request.getParameter("SP"))%>';
                document.getElementById("SP").value = SP;
                var AAS = '<%=Integer.parseInt((request.getParameter("AAS") == null) ? "0" : request.getParameter("AAS"))%>';
                document.getElementById("AAS").value = AAS;
                var PDI = '<%=Integer.parseInt((request.getParameter("PDI") == null) ? "0" : request.getParameter("PDI"))%>';
                document.getElementById("PDI").value = PDI;
                //inicio



                if (SP > 0 || seguro == 3) {


                    var tope;

                    a = 0;

                    b = 0;

                    r = 0;

                    c = 0;

                    //selecciona el valor del tope

                    //if (!(seguro==1))

                    // tope=0;

                    //else

                    tope = SP;

                    //-------------------------------------

                    c = ((FIJO1 * 12) / 365) * 25;

                    b = SP * 365 / 12;

                    //verifica que no se exceda el tope

                    if (tope <= c) {
                        //asigna el valor de la Cuantia Basica
                        if (seguro == 1) {
                            b = b * 0.35;
                        } else {
                            b = b * 0.70;
                        }
                        if (seguro == 3) {
                            window.document.getElementById("CB").value = outputMoney(FIJO2);
                        } else {
                            window.document.getElementById("CB").value = outputMoney(b);
                        }
                        //datos de a y b para cada combinación

                        //verficar el TdS

                        if (seguro == 1) {
                            //Vericar para cada TdP

                            if (pension == 1) {
                                string_pension = "Invalidez";
                                //if (forma.TdSIV.checked && forma.TdPInvalidez.checked) {

                                r = (HON * .1) + (AAS / 100) + 1;

                                if (esposa == "true") {
                                    r = r + 0.15;
                                }

                                r = Max(FIJO2, r * b);

                                a = Max(FIJO2, b);

                            }

                            //-------------------------------------

                            else if (pension == 3) {
                                string_pension = "Viudez y Orfandad";
                                //else if (forma.TdSIV.checked && forma.TdPVO.checked) {

                                r = 0.9 + (HOS * 0.2) + (HOD * 0.3);

                                if (r > 1) {
                                    r = Max(FIJO2, b);
                                } else
                                    r = Max(FIJO2, b) * r;

                                a = r;

                            }

                            //-------------------------------------
                            else if (pension == 4) {
                                string_pension = "Viudez";
                                //else if (forma.TdSIV.checked && forma.TdPVI.checked)   {

                                r = Max(FIJO2, b) * 0.9;

                                a = r;

                            }

                            //-------------------------------------

                            else if (pension == 5) {
                                string_pension = "Orfandad";
                                //else if (forma.TdSIV.checked && forma.TdPOR.checked) {

                                r = HOS * 0.2 + HOD * 0.3;

                                if (r > 1) {
                                    a = Max(FIJO2, b);

                                    r = a;

                                } else {
                                    r = Max(FIJO2, b) * r;

                                    a = r;

                                }

                            }

                            //-------------------------------------

                            else if (pension == 6) {
                                string_pension = "Ascendencia";
                                //else if (forma.TdSIV.checked && forma.TdPASC.checked)         {

                                r = ASC * 0.2;

                                a = Max(FIJO2, b) * r;

                                r = a;

                            }

                        }//fin de verificar TdSIV

                        else if (seguro == 2) {
                            //-------------------------------------

                            if (pension == 2) {
                                string_pension = "Incapacidad";
                                //else if (forma.TdSRT.checked && forma.TdPIncapacidad.checked) {

                                r = (PDI / 100) * Max(b, FIJO2);

                                if (PDI > 50) {
                                    a = r * 0.5;
                                }
                            }

                            //-------------------------------------

                            else if (pension == 3) {
                                string_pension = "Viudez y Orfandad";
                                //else if (forma.TdSRT.checked && forma.TdPVO.checked) {
                                r = Max(0.4, ((0.9 * FIJO2) / Max(FIJO2, b)))
                                        + (HOS * 0.2) + (HOD * 0.3);

                                if (r > 1) {
                                    a = ((Max(0.4, ((0.9 * FIJO2) / Max(FIJO2, b))) + HOD * 0.3) / r)
                                            * 0.5 * Max(FIJO2, b);

                                    r = Max(FIJO2, b);

                                } else {
                                    a = (Max(0.4, ((0.9 * FIJO2) / Max(FIJO2, b))) + HOD * 0.3)
                                            * 0.5 * Max(FIJO2, b);

                                    r = Max(FIJO2, b) * r;

                                }

                            }

                            //-------------------------------------

                            else if (pension == 4) {
                                //else if (forma.TdSRT.checked && forma.TdPVI.checked) {

                                r = Max(0.4, ((0.9 * FIJO2) / Max(FIJO2, b)))
                                        * Max(FIJO2, b);

                                a = r * 0.5;

                            }

                            //-------------------------------------

                            else if (pension == 5) {
                                //else if (forma.TdSRT.checked && forma.TdPOR.checked)   {

                                r = HOS * 0.2 + HOD * 0.3;

                                if (r > 1) {
                                    a = ((HOD * 0.3) / r) * Max(FIJO2, b) * 0.5;

                                    r = Max(FIJO2, b);

                                } else {
                                    r = Max(FIJO2, b) * r;

                                    a = HOD * 0.3 * Max(FIJO2, b) * 0.5;

                                }

                            }

                            //-------------------------------------

                            else if (pension == 6) {
                                //else if (forma.TdSRT.checked && forma.TdPASC.checked)  {

                                r = ASC * 0.2;

                                a = Max(FIJO2, b) * r * 0.5;

                                r = Max(FIJO2, b) * r;

                            }

                        }//fin TdSRT

                        else if (seguro == 3) {
                            //-------------------------------------

                            if (pension == 3) {
                                r = 0.9 + HOS * 0.2 + HOD * 0.3;

                                if (r > 1) {
                                    r = FIJO2;

                                    a = 0;

                                } else {
                                    r = FIJO2 * r;

                                    a = 0;

                                }

                            }

                            //-------------------------------------

                            else if (pension == 4) {
                                r = FIJO2 * 0.9;

                                a = 0;

                            }

                            //-------------------------------------

                            else if (pension == 5) {
                                r = HOS * 0.2 + HOD * 0.3;

                                if (r > 1) {
                                    a = FIJO2;

                                    r = 0;

                                } else {
                                    r = FIJO2 * r;

                                    a = 0;

                                }

                            }

                            //-------------------------------------

                            else if (pension == 6) {
                                r = ASC * 0.2;

                                a = 0;

                                r = FIJO2 * r;

                            }

                        }//fin TdSRCV

                        //-------------------------------------

                        if (b < FIJO2) {
                            window.document.getElementById("CB").value = outputMoney(FIJO2);
                        }
                        window.document.getElementById("PM").value = outputMoney(r);
                        setPaymentAmount(($('#PM').val()).replace(",", ""));

                        window.document.getElementById("AG").value = outputMoney(a);

                    } else {
                        alert("El Salario Pensionable debe ser menor a 25 veces el salario mínimo vigente.");
                        //nuevo Cambio
                        window.location = '/aplicativos/simulador-pensiones/paso-03.jsp?pension=' + pension + '&seguro=' + seguro;
                        //llamar a reset valores de abajo....

                        //reset sp

                    }//fin checartope

                }//fin if sp>0

                else {
                    alert("El Salario Pensionable no puede ser 0");

                }
            });


        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Simulador Pensión</h1>
            <h2>Calculo de Pensión por Montos Solicitados.</h2>
            <h3>Resultados</h3>
            <form name="paso04" method="post" action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="HON" id="HON" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="HOS" id="HOS" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="HOD" id="HOD" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="ASC" id="ASC" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="esposa" id="esposa" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="seguro" id="seguro" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="pension" id="pension" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="SP" id="SP" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="AAS" id="AAS" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="PDI" id="PDI" value="">
                <div class="botonera1">  
                    <div id="bt_div" class="derecha">
                        <div class="group">
                            <select class="Caja_txt_246" tabindex="9">
                                <option name="valorpension" id="actual" value="1">Actual</option>
                                <option name="valorpension" id="anterior" value="2">Anterior</option>

                            </select>

                            <label class="combo">Pensión mínima garantizada:</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="botonera1">
                    <div id="bt_div" class="derecha">
                    <div class="group">
                        <!--<input name="CB" type="text"  id="CB" value="" readonly="readonly">-->

                        <input class="inputsChicos" name="CB" type="text"  id="CB" value="" readonly="readonly" >

                        <label>Cuantía Básica:</label>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="botonera1">
                    <div id="bt_div" class="derecha">
                    <div class="group">
                        <input class="inputsChicos" name="PM" type="text"   id="PM" value="" readonly="readonly">
                        <label>Pensión mensual:</label>

                    </div>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="botonera1">
                    <div id="bt_div" class="derecha">
                    <div class="group">
                        <!--<input class="inputsChicos" name="AG" type="text"  id="AG" value="" readonly="readonly" >-->
                        <input class="inputsChicos" name="AG" type="text"  id="AG" value="" readonly="readonly">
                        <label>Aguinaldo:</label>

                    </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

               <div class="botonera1">
                   <div id="bt_div" class="derecha">
                    <div class="group">
                        <input class="inputsChicos" name="PMG" type="text"  id="PMG" value="" readonly="readonly">

                    </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="botonera">
                        <div id="bt_div" class="derecha exiit">
                            <a href="" class="exit">Regresar</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="bt_div" class="izquierda">
                            <button type="submit" id="loginButton" >Aceptar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
            </form>
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            setVersionDL();
            setPageInstanceID("des");
            setPageIntent("informacion");
            setPageSegment("personas");
            setSysEnv("escritorio");
            setChannel("online");
            setLanguage("ES");
            setGeoRegion("MX");
            setLevel(1, "pensiones");
            setLevel(2, "simulador pensiones");
            setLevel(3, "pagina exitosa");
            setArea("publica");
            setPageName();
            setServer();
            setBussinessUnit("BBVA Bancomer");
            setMobile();
            setUserState("no logado");
            setType("simulador");
            setName("simulador pensiones");
            setFulfillmentModel("online");
            setStep("pagina exitosa");
            setState("finalizado");
            setPrimaryCategory("inversiones");
            setProductName(string_pension.toLowerCase());
            setProductSubtype("planes de pensiones");
            setTypology("");           
        </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">_satellite.pageBottom();</script>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Posiblemente el problema se encuentre aqui:

```js
$('input[name=valorpension]').click(function () {
    if ($('input:radio[name=valorpension]:checked').val() == 1) {
        $('#PMG').val(FIJO2);
    } else if ($('input:radio[name=valorpension]:checked').val() == 2)
        $('#PMG').val(FIJO3);
});
```

Por ultimo es la vista:

[image]

Así como se ven los números, ese calculo se tiene que ver en un input que esta oculto de lado derecho de donde dice aguinaldo

Espero y me puedan brindar de su apoyo por favor, de antemano les mando cordial saludo.

Comment: Buenas, creo haber entendido que estarías necesitando que en el cambio de un DropDown se actualice un input que tenes oculto con determinado valor.
en tal caso, fijate si te sirve esto,
<https://jsfiddle.net/nxnmcmnj/>, Decime si al menos te orienta un poco a lo que necesitas. Por otro lado, no se como continua el flujo de tu aplicación pero, en el caso que tengas en enviar un formulario podrías leer directamente del dropdown. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui esta la solución amigos, sALUDOS Y BUENA VIBRA:

```
     $(".Caja_txt_246")
                        .change(function () {
                            if ($('select option:selected[name=valorpension]:selected').val() == 1) {
                                $('#PMG').val(FIJO2);
//                                str += $(this).text() + " ";
                            } else if ($('select option:selected[name=valorpension]:selected').val() == 2)
                                $('#PMG').val(FIJO3);
//                            str += $(this).text() + " ";
                        });
```

Comment: Juan, agrega una explicación de lo que realiza el código, es importante para que ayude a otros desarrolladores, te recomiendo revisar [answer], después incluso puedes marcar esto como solución.